# How can I get SalesForce to turn an email message into a new Lead with a new Case attached to it?

Tags: email, crm

I'd like to have emails coming into an "info@company.com" email address automatically turn into a new Lead with a new Case attached to it, in SalesForce. What's the easiest way to get that done?

I've tried auto forwarding all incoming emails to the "Email-to-Service" email address, but that only creates Leads with the email attached to them as an EmailMessage. I've tried doing the same with "Email-to-Case" but that only creates a new Case with no Lead attached.

Is there any way to enable one of these features to do what I need? Are there alternatives? I'm a software developer so solutions involving coding are welcome too.

Comment: PS - I hope this is on-topic here. And if it is, can someone please tag this with a "salesforce" tag? I don't have enough credit :|

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you can NOT create a case to a lead - it's not a valid connection according to SF Scheme.

If you insist on this, what I think you should do is write your own mailgrabber, and from that, you can use SF API (Currently 18 I think) and just create any objects you may need.

The right procedure will be:
First you will need to create a new custom object: Lead_Case__c

- Grab email from info@company.com mailbox
- create a new Lead
- Create a new Lead_Case__c

You are done.

IMO, I think it's an overkill, there are reasons why a Lead can not have a case attached to i - you can create a task or event to remind you to interact with that lead.

Also, you may look into SF new features released lately - I think you will find that using the Email-integration is better now.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by embedding a salesforce form builder software that has email integration feature. There are few form builders that can do the job. [Formtitan](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EvaSKUAZ&tab=r/%22formtitan%20%22) is a perfect fit for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is old... and I'm putting this answer out to anyone else.
1.) There is not "native" email-to-lead feature.
2.) There are apps on the appexchange that will do this as of Feb 2021.
3.) If you do use email-to-CASE, an "orphan" Contact would be created, which you could "treat as a lead", but it would NOT be a LEAD RECORD, it would be a CONTACT record.
So, your entire LEAD DATA strategy might be served to NOT USE the LEAD RECORD, but instead treat Orphan (or Private) Contacts as Leads.

Depending on how many EMAILS you receive as a Lead, you could just as easily, do nothing, except Use the Salesforce Chrome Extension or Outlook Add-In that connects Salesforce to your email client (Google/Outlook) and just add the Unknown Email (ie-not already in your database) to Salesforce as a Lead.

Salesforce does it's features VERY WELL, don't try to FORCE things to work different, just use its powers they way they were designed and you will find that ALL things work better.